# how to get back the compressed string back from uncompressed string using zlib python?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, zlib

I have a compressed string `"H4sIAAAAAAAEACtmyGBIZMhjKAHTALXiaIAOAAAA"` which is produced by C# code. I tried to decompress the same using zlib as below:

```
c = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode("H4sIAAAAAAAEACtmyGBIZMhjKAHTALXiaIAOAAAA"), 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
print(c)
print(c.decode('utf-8'))
```

Output of the above code snippet is : `shantha`

Now, how can I get back the compressed string `"H4sIAAAAAAAEACtmyGBIZMhjKAHTALXiaIAOAAAA"` from the original string `"shantha"` using zlib?

Edit:
C# code which created the compressed string:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string plainText = "shantha";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);  
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, compressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            gZipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        var compressedData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
        memoryStream.Read(compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);
        var gZipBuffer = new byte[compressedData.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(compressedData, 0, gZipBuffer, 0, compressedData.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(gZipBuffer));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code returns `s h a n t h a` on my end. `c.decode("utf-16")` however returns `shantha`.

Comment: I'm having a hard time to try to encode the string back into the correct compression. You don't happen to have the code that created the compressed string itself?

Comment: I have it. But it is in C#.

Comment: Post it. You can ask about two languages in the same question if the codes are linked, as this is.

Comment: @Hampus Laarsson - Posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "shantha". That Base-64 encoded zlib stream decodes to `b"s\0h\0a\0n\0t\0h\0a\0"`. There are a bunch of nulls interspersed with the characters that don't show when you print it. (Per Hampus' comment, that was likely due to encoding the string as UTF-16 before compression.)

Your original string is gzip encoded, not zlib. So you will need to use `zlib.compressobj` with `wbits=31` to generate the zlib format. Example, including encoding to UTF-16, little-endian, typed into interactive Python:

```
>>> import zlib
>>> import base64
>>> s = "shantha".encode('utf-16le')
>>> z = zlib.compressobj(wbits=31)
>>> c = z.compress(s)
>>> c += z.flush(zlib.Z_FINISH)
>>> base64.b64encode(c)
b'H4sIAAAAAAAAEytmyGBIZMhjKAHTALXiaIAOAAAA'
```

The gzip header generated may be slightly different, as it is here, depending on what operating system you're running on and what the compression level was. Also for larger inputs and other compression levels or versions of the software, the compressed data may vary as well. But that doesn't matter. All that matters is that you get the original data back when you decompress.

Comment: Isn't `16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS` already `31` though? Also, the "nulls" are there because it's a `utf-16le` string, not a `utf-8" as he's trying to decode it as.

Comment: Yes, but that's in their _decompression_ example, where interestingly it's not even needed. (`decompress` will detect the gzip format and decompress it without that option.) If they want to make a compressed stream like that, they need to use `31` (or `16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS`). However, `compress` in Python does not have that option! (Don't know why not.) So they would have to use the `compressobj` interface as noted in the answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize why there were all those nulls in there. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkAdler - Can please add here example for zlib.compressobj with wbits=31 to generate the zlib format?

Comment: Using gzip, we should be able to get this string back right? - "H4sIAAAAAAAEACtmyGBIZMhjKAHTALXiaIAOAAAA"

Comment: Not exactly, no. But it doesn't need to be exact. It just needs to decompress to the original.

Comment: Brilliant answer! I was stuck on my side of the equation asking myself why my encoded string wasn't the same as the one given by OP. Silly of me to not try to remove the encoding to see that it contained the same information, just packaged a bit differently.